# Is it possible to disable mac gatekeeper by extension?

Tags: macos, libreoffice, osx-gatekeeper

I want to be warned by Mac gatekeeper whenever I attempt to use an app for the first time that is not signed through the store. However, I'm having trouble using LibreOffice Vanilla by clicking on files with relevant extensions (eg .ods, .odt). It seems to consider each file a different app and I think needs me to authorize it individually. Double-clicking file yeilds '"myfile.odt” can’t be opened because it is from an unidentified developer.'

Right-clicking and using Open with ... LibreOffice Vanilla yeilds:
'"myfile.odt” is from an unidentified developer. Are you sure you want to open it?'

I don't find the 'help' at https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT202491 helpful. How can I configure OS X so it lets me open LibreOffice files with a double-click yet still have GateKeeper check other new applications that are not signed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bypass gatekeeper if you select a file type to "always open with" a certain type of program. Other programs that are not of this type will still invoke gatekeeper, so you won't have the security issues. So if you set your .odt file type to always open with libreoffice, the issue should go away.

See **this**:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193233/gatekeeper-wont-let-libreoffice-open-csv-files